# Backbone.js audio control

Tags: javascript, audio, backbone.js

I have a Backbone view, it uses an html template, placed on the page:

```
<script type="text/template" id="webphone-template">
            <audio id="audio-ringtone" src="{% static "prime_app/assets/audio/ringtone.mp3" %}"></audio>
            <div class="well">
                <p class="text-muted text-center"><%= status %></p>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <button id="btn-webphone-answer" class="btn btn-success">
                        <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button id="btn-webphone-terminate" class="btn btn-danger">
                        <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </script>
```

My view has method ring(), which looks like this:

```
ring: function() {
        $("#audio-ringtone").get(0).play();
    }
```

But when this method is invoked audio doesn't play, no errors in JS console, the audio element is chosen correctly. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, there was the following problem: audio-tag is in my view's element, when i call render(), it completely replaces all the HTML inside element, so if there is audio-element it just gets removed and the sound doesn't play anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Well i dont know how your whole view works, if you add it i can modify the code, but i got it to work fairly easy. Again, i need to see your view code to see what youre doing wrong.

```
View = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#webphone-template').html()),
    events: {
        'click #btn-webphone-answer': 'ring'
    },
    initialize: function(opt) {
        // attach to the main body
        $(opt['main']).append(this.el)
        this.status = 'paused';
        this.render();
    },
    ring: function() {
        $(this.el).find('#audio-ringtone')[0].play()
    },
    render: function() {
        $(this.el).append(this.template({status: this.status}));

        return this;
    }
});

new View({ main: $('body') });
```

works: http://jsfiddle.net/hLero5rd/